# how to remove ".mp3" from "xxx.mp3" string

Tags: java, android

i want to make a music player, i have a problem to toast file name because it always includes the extension(".mp3")

does anyone know how to remove those extension?

this is my code

```
try {
    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nama , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

and

```
music_column_index=
    musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
nama = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
```

i want to make it toast "xx" not "xx.mp3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but does nama give you the xx.mp3? If so:

```
nama = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index).substring(0, musiccursor.getString(music_column_index).lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String name = "Jai_Ho.mp3"
String nameWithoutExtension = name.subString(0,name.lastIndexOf("."));
```

---

**See Also**

- [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 2):

just `filename = filename.replaceFirst("\\.mp3$", "");`

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "xx.mp3";
    s= s.replace(".mp3","");
    System.out.println(s);
```